# i am trying to update product inventory level for every sku in bigcommerce api

Tags: php

I am trying to update configurable product inventory level for a particular SKU in Bigcommerce. For that i am using following code, it is working for simple products but not for configurable products.

The array for updating the product was:

```
$qtyarr = array("inventory_level"=>7775);
```

And here updateproduct is the function of BigCommerce API in which we are passing two argument.
One is the product_id and another one is the array.

```
$allproducts = BigCommerce_Api::updateProduct('112',$qtyarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a SKU has inventory on it's own object, not on the product object.  It is the difference of working with the product resource here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#products-reference

and it's SKU subresource:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#skus

What you need to do is first pull the list of SKUs from the product with a call like this:

`$array_of_skus = BigCommerce_Api::getCollection('/products/112/skus?limit=250');`

Once you have your list of skus, you can iterate through each of the SKU objects and update inventory on each SKU individually, ie:

`foreach($array_of_skus as $sku){
   BigCommerce_Api::updateSku( $sku->id, array("inventory_level" => 7775));
}`

Comment: The updateSKu function was not available in API documentation of BigCommerce. Can You please provide the udpateSku function to us.

Comment: Hi @GovindGarge, did you try using the code I suggested?  The `updateSku()` method may not being showing in the documentation about the PHP API SDK found here:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

But it is still part of the code in the current version of the SDK.  You can find the definition for the `updateSku()` method here:
https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/blob/master/src/Bigcommerce/Api/Client.php#L1210-L1214

Not all available methods are documented but you can read through the library files (specifically `Client.php`) to find them or add more.

Comment: If your local copy of the Bigcommerce PHP API SDK does not have the `updateSKU()` method in the `Client` class then you need to pull the newest version of the library from the BigCommerce github repository.  Alternatively you could add the code I referenced into your local copy manually or achieve the same using the `updateResource()` method.